# Android: Disable backpress action in activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app for one of the activity i have a instruction screen(transparent activity ) on top of the activity ,

```
  public class quickActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quicktip);


        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {



            @Override
            public  boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                quicktipActivity.this.finish();
                return false;

            }});}}
```

when i back press the device button i can see the below activity, i want the back button to be disabled when transparent activity is on top  Any suggestions how can i achieve this.

Comment: you don't seem to be in the activity you started. what is `activity`, anyway ?

Comment: iam calling the trasparent activity in oncreate method of the below activity.

Comment: try changing "activity.finish()" to "quicktipActivity.this.finish()"

Comment: what is activity, anyway ?

Comment: @EJK quicktipActivity.this.finish() not working

Comment: Are you sure that onTouch is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: just over rided onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       // Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On top activity, you should override onBackPressed and do the stuff you want to do:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()